# Pagination with MS Access?

Tags: sql, pagination

I would like to page my database over 100 pages, each 1 percent at a time... The only problem is this database is an MS Access database(not by choice). My current sql statement in my code is

```
$sql= "SELECT TOP 1 PERCENT * FROM [Drive Errors] ORDER BY [Position]ASC";
```

Is this even possible due to the top function pulling from only the top of the database?

Comment: Is it important to paginate by percentage instead of by fixed amount, say, 100 rows per page?

Comment: No either way would work, it is just that there are about 4000 rows

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1564024/ms-access-limit