# MS Access get first, second, third etc. values

Tags: ms-access

I have 2 tables, Tags and Certs, in a one-to-many relationship - each tag will have anywhere between 0 and 10+ certs associated with it.

```
Tags                       Certs
[Tag] [Other fields]       [Tag]    [Date]     [Length]
A-22       ...             A-22    03/05/17      265
P-63       ...             A-22    15/02/14      331
...                        A-22    09/12/12      656
                           P-63    01/02/12      1024
                           ...
```

Is there a way to return the most recent, second most recent, third most etc. length for each Tag as different fields?

My ideal end product would look something like:

```
[Tag] [Most recent length] [Second most recent] [third most] ...
A-22          265                  331              656
P-63          1024
...
```

This issue is especially grating since I recently ported it from MySQL, which has the LIMIT clause which solved this easily. I'm aware there is no direct equivalent (from [MS Access Limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1564024/ms-access-limit)), but I'm wondering if there is some other way to achieve what I need.

Comment: Just wondering, but what about a [a crosstab query](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/make-summary-data-easier-to-read-by-using-a-crosstab-query-8465b89c-2ff2-4cc8-ba60-2cd8484667e8?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) ? Maybe you could cross data of every of your tags with dates in columns, from most recent to older one

Comment: Sorry, just realised I need length values, not date. Question edited

Comment: The solution would be the same probably. From min to max

Comment: This is not easy in Access.  I think you can get what you want by creating a [Ranking query](http://allenbrowne.com/ranking.html#query) and then using that as the data source for a crosstab.

Comment: @HansUp, Foxfire: Thank you! I was able to find a solution using those links. Posting it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to HansUp and Foxfire, I was able to find a solution. Posting here so it can maybe help others having a similar problem.

First step was to construct a ranking query from the Certs table:

```
SELECT t1.[Tag], t1.[Date], t1.[Length], COUNT(t1.[Date]) AS Rank
FROM [Certs] AS t1, [Certs] AS t2
WHERE (t1.[Date] <= t2.[Date]) AND t1.[Tag] = t2.[Tag]
GROUP BY t1.[Tag], t1.[Date], t1.[Length]
ORDER BY t1.[Tag];
```

Which gave the result:

```
[Tag]    [Date]     [Length]   [Rank]
A-22    03/05/17      265        1
A-22    15/02/14      331        2
A-22    09/12/12      656        3
P-63    01/02/12      1024       1
...
```

From there a simple crosstab query constructed from the wizard with [Tag] as row headers, [Rank] as column headers, and MAX([Length]) as values, produced the desired table in the question.